# Why my last cell loses its background color and its content

Tags: swift, uitableview

Here is my code where I can't get why I lose my last cell features:

```
extension ItemsViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath)

        let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.section]

        if indexPath.row == item.count {
            let lastCell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "lastCell")
            lastCell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1)
            lastCell.textLabel?.text = "No more Items"
            return lastCell
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = item[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(item[indexPath.row].valueInDollars)"


        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return section == 0 ? "below 50" : "above 50"
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemStore.allItems[section].count + 1
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return indexPath.row == itemStore.allItems[indexPath.section].count - 1 ? 44 : 60
    }
}
```

If I do not use the last method (`heightForRowAt`) then everything works fine. But if I use it I get correct sizes for cell but I lose content for the last cell and its color as well.

Comment: If all you are doing is adding a cell to the last index with an indication that it is the bottom of the list in your tableView why not simply use viewForFooterInSection and add a label to it?

Comment: Why are you returning `return itemStore.allItems[section].count + 1`? This should return the actual count: `return itemStore.allItems[section].count`.

Comment: only thing that seems odd is `indexPath.row == itemStore.allItems[indexPath.section].count - 1 ? 44 : 60` - I would guess you wanted: `indexPath.row == itemStore.allItems[indexPath.section].count ? 44 : 60`, however, that should definitely not cause the problems you are mentioning..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a correct answer. Use the following `cellForRow` implementation instead of yours:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Do not dequeue the cell here, because two lines below you might decide that you do not want to use it
    // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath)

    let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.section]

    if indexPath.row == item.count {
        let lastCell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "lastCell")
        lastCell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1)
        lastCell.textLabel?.text = "No more Items"
        return lastCell
    }

    // Dequeue reusable cell here, when you know you are going to use it:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = item[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(item[indexPath.row].valueInDollars)"


    return cell
}
```

The only difference is that you dequeue reuseable cell only after the test, only when you know that you are going to use the dequeued cell. Tableview obviously expects you to return that cell if you have already dequeued it. It probably uses it to make rendering more effective and it renders the cell even before you really return it (and modify only what you change later), and thus it seems that your code for the last cell does not work (it works, but before you return your last cell the table renders the dequeued cell).

The moral of the story: **If you dequeue a reusable cell for a given indexPath, the tableView expects you to really also return it**.

Official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell):

> This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available, or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered, **and adds it to the table.**

Be dequeuing the cell for the specified indexPath, you are already adding it to the table. That means that if you used `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` instead of `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`, then the order of calls would not matter, because `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` would not add it to the table for you. However, I would still rather go with my solution, and dequeue it only when you need it.

Comment: Thank you Milan! Neat moment for me.

Answer (score 1):

On initial glance,

```
if indexPath.row == item.count {
```

I believe the error might be there. Print out the count of each.  You might get 1 less for indexPath.  Therefore, the last content won't be set.

Haven't run the code yet.

Comment: exactly my first thought. however, if you check the numberOfRows, he is returning item.count + 1, so it should be fine

Comment: it will still be out of sync because index starts off at 0.  So you have indexes [0,1,2,3,4] = 5 and item.count = [1,2,3,4,5] + 1 = 6 for e.g.

Comment: trust me, it's good. item.count + 1 is the number of rows in the table.. last index is skipped by the if test and it is used for the last cell

Comment: looks like it should be if indexPath.row + 1 == item.count { then?

Comment: no, it's good. indexPath.row == item.count. row with index 6 is the seventh row (since it starts from 0), so if this 6 is equal to item.count, then it is the last cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register the `lastCell`,then use dequeueReusableCell to load cell, here is the code:

```
if indexPath.row == item.count {
        let lastCell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "lastCell")
        lastCell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1)
        lastCell.textLabel?.text = "No more Items"
        return lastCell
}
```

replaced by:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"lastCell")

if indexPath.row == item.count {
        let lastCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lastCell", for: indexPath)
        lastCell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1)
        lastCell.textLabel?.text = "No more Items"
        return lastCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == item.count {
        // Place your desired color for the last cell.
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else {
        // This should be the normal cell background color.
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

For your requirement a single reusable cell will be sufficient. Assuming you have already registered a cell with identifier "MyTableViewCellIdentifier".
See the below method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.section]

    if indexPath.row == item.count {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No more Items"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = nil
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = item[indexPath.row].name

        let valueInDollars = item[indexPath.row].valueInDollars
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = $ + valueInDollars
    }

    return cell
}
```

(Swift 3)